# Except if vs Unless

Tags: word-choice, difference

Is there a difference between **except if** and **unless**? Which is more common?

- Unless it rains tomorrow we are planning on going to the park.
- Except if it rains tomorrow we are planning on going to the park.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, when we exclude technical books on software and programming, and focus instead on other kinds of prose, it is unusual for a sentence to start with **Except if**. Most often, an *except if*-clause is added on as a qualifier after the matrix clause rather than used as an opening condition. On the other hand,  *unless*-clauses appear before and after the matrix clause.

Comment: So it's wrong to use **except if** as an opening condition or is it simply better to avoid it and use **unless** instead?

Comment: I'd use **unless** instead.

Answer (score 1):

They're pretty much the same thing. *Unless* is more common and combines condition with exception (except + if), hence the negative meaning; *provided (that)* and its synonyms are the positive equivalent. *Except if* sounds clunky on its own but works well enough with preceding context:

> “But it always says something like that on the boxes you get games in,” said Johnny. **Except if** you get them from Wobbler, he added to himself, when you just get a disk.